# SUM of dynamic row in phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

I am the biginner of phpexcel I am facing problem to sum up the dynamic row.
Normally the code will be

```
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue(AB45,"=SUM(AB25:AB44)" );
```

how about the dynamic row?? the below is my code

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('AB'.$col, "=SUM(AB25:AB".($col).")");
```

Appreaciate your help~

Comment: I'd have thought `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('AB'.$row, "=SUM(AB25:AB".($row-1).")");`

Comment: @MarkBaker Since its correct answer write it as such. Then it can be accepted.